# How to tidy and expand my partitions after Windows removal from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I recently removed the Windows part of my dual boot drive. I now just have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I now want to maximize the amount of disk space my remaining Ubuntu partition has and to tidy things up.

I am looking at Gparted:

[image]

I see that:

- Ubuntu seems to be installed on sda5
- The swap-space is on sda6 and is 15.88 GB. Is this too large?
- I have RECOVERY on sda7. Is this related to Windows? Do I still need
  this.
- I have lots of free space after removing Windows

**I want to remove anythings that I don't need and want to maximize the space for my Ubuntu partition.**

I'm aware that I need to make any changes while using a bootable USB drive version of Ubuntu.

Any help in the steps to do this would be gratefully received.

Comment: It seems you are asking [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) The RECOVERY on `sda7` is probably Windows, and you won't need it, unless you want to erase everything and reinstall Windows. Even then, I don't know if the "recovery" will work after all the changes.